# How to export and import data in a .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid App (if possible)?

Tags: .net, export-to-csv, maui-blazor

What options do I have to exchange data from a Maui Blazor Hybrid App. Can I create a .csv file and save it to the 'download'-folder of an android phone? Like saving a .pdf from a browser. What must be done do to that? In my case I want to back up a database file from LiteDB and later read that file back in. Csv would be okay to. I don't want to use Email.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please add the following permission about storage in the **Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />    
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos that other apps created -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos that other apps created -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access audio files that other apps created -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

And then check the storage permission at run time. Put the following code in the **Platforms\Android\MainActivity**

```
    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33 && Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>().Result == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        }
    }
```

And then create the file and write or read it:

```
#if ANDROID
        FileStream fileStreamen = new FileStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/myyyx.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        File.WriteAllText("/storage/emulated/0/Download/my.txt", "Hello");
#endif
```

**Note:** I used the `/storage/emulated/0/Download` because the api about getting public folder's path was deprecated. But `/storage/emulated/0/Download` still work.

**Update:**

The files in the first and second steps you can file in the **\Platforms\Android** folder of the project solution structure. And you can copy the code into the files. And for the AndroidManifest.xml you can open it with the xml editor and then copy code.

And for the third step, you can refer to the following code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateFileAndWrite">Click me</button>

@code { 
    private void CreateFileAndWrite()
    {
#if ANDROID
        FileStream fileStreamen = new FileStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/myyyx.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        File.WriteAllText("/storage/emulated/0/Download/my.txt", "Hello");
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain just a little bit more how to use this in a .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid App. I have no experiance in Xamarin.

Comment: Please refer to the update part in my answer. @nogood